# About vertical slider height calculation

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

I'm trying to implement a vertical slider using the 1.8.1 version of slick.js.
However, due to the calculation of the vertical slider, it is not displayed correctly.

Occasionally it displays a shorter length than it should after loading the page.

Specifically, although three images are displayed, only two heights are displayed.

What's even weirder is that pressing the Arrow button (maximum 2 times) restores the original length.

How can I get the true length to be displayed regardless of the variable size of the page?

slick.js gives the `div` tag with the "slick-list" class the computed result directly in the `style` tag.

I'm not sure if the height or width of the parent element is the problem, or if it's the FlexItem effect...

**JavaScript**

```
    $('.slider').slick({

        vertical: true,

        slidesToShow: 3,

        slidesToScroll: 1,

        arrows: true,

        swipe: false,

        speed: 200,

        infinite: false,

        adaptiveHeight: true,

    });
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 90px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Are all the images fully loaded before slick is invoked?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I am running the js after loading the image with $(window).on('load',...
However, when crossing breakpoints in a responsive layout, the width becomes strange.

Should I do "$(window).on('load',..." for each breakpoint?

Comment: I honestly don’t know enough about how that system works. Might be worth a try because I can’t think of what else would give the variable results you are seeing, it feels like a timing problem.

Comment: _"Should I do "$(window).on('load',..." for each breakpoint?"_ - no; if you want different slider settings for different breakpoints, then you should use the `responsive` option as shown in the example titled "Responsive Display", https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#demos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feasible workaround by adding JS code to slick.js file. We can only show part of it here because both JS components need to be in separate JS files.
See github posts:
[github article](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1803)
[github article also](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/4019)

Example for vertical adaptive height slider (tested in chromium, edge, ff).
[codepen example](https://codepen.io/crux1/pen/BaPPPjg)

```
<script>
$('.vertigo').slick({
  rows: 0,
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  autoplaySpeed: 4000,
  centerMode: false,
  centerPadding: '0',
  variableWidth: false,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  responsive: [
        {
        breakpoint: 993,
            settings: {
            centerMode: false,
            variableWidth: false,
            },
        },
    ]
});
</script>
```